# Pandas to_excel not working when trying to write a dataframe on an empty xlsx file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Having this code:

```
tlfx = pandas.DataFrame()   
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(file)
writer.book = load_workbook(file)
writer.sheets = dict((register.title, register) for register in writer.book.worksheets)
tlfx = tlfx.append({'Name': person, 'Telephone': telephone}, ignore_index=True)
reader = pandas.read_excel(r'' + file + '')
if reader.empty:
  tlfx.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=True, startrow=0)
else:
  tlfx.to_excel(writer, index=False, header=False, startrow=len(reader) + 1)
writer.close()
```

The idea is basically to write the headers only if the .xlsx file has no data in it. Otherwise, it'll ignore the headers and just write the person and the phone number.

However, the "to_excel" function works only if the .xlsx already has data in it, so despite correctly entering the "if" statement, nothing happens within the excel file.

Why is this happening and how could I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The error was here:
pandas.to_excel function was creating a new sheet with the default name "Sheet_1", and all the data went there.
To fix it, I used writer.book.active.title as the value for the sheet_name parameter in the to_excel() function.